# Getting an Error when trying to output every combination of values in a matrix using R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to replace the values in a data frame with every combination of values and then outputting them in a matrix. However, I get an error then I run it. Below is the code and a sample data.

```
test_data=array(0,c(14^4,5,1))
for (a in seq(14)){
  for (b in seq(14)){
    for (c in seq(14)){
      for (d in seq(14)){
        if(a+b+c+d==4){n=1}else{n=n+1}
        test.set[1,]=c(a,b,c,d)
        test_data[n,,2] =c(a,b,c,d,as.vector(predict(quant.reg,test.set)))
      }
    }
  }
} 
test.set sample

               rank1             rank2            rank3              rank4
2                1                  1                1                  1
5                6                  9                9                 10
8               14                  6               13                  8
12              14                 11               10                  1
16               6                  6                6                  9
18               5                  7                6                  8

quant.reg is a "lm" class

Error in test_data[n, , 2] <- c(a, b, c, d, predict(quant.reg,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any help regarding this error is appreciated. Since I'm new to R, I'm also open to a better approach.

Comment: wouldn't `expand.grid` save you the hassle of those for loops.

Comment: oh, I have never heard of expand.grid. I will check it out.

Comment: I do not think I can use predict() with expand.grid. In the code I'm also outputting the result of the predict() with the combinations.

Comment: Well yeah, but you can use expand.grid to build your data-frame of predictors and then pass that in as the `newdata` to your `predict` function

Comment: Thanks for the approach! I will try it.